# disable a centering effect

Tags: tables

In fact I have set a table in latex which is centered but the problem is what comes atfer the table is remained centered. How can I get a normal text after my table, here is the code :

```
 \documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,nccmath}
 \usepackage{cclicenses}
 \usepackage{makecell}
 \usepackage{subcaption}
 \usepackage{caption}
 \usepackage{framed}  % Framing content
 \usepackage{nomencl} % Nomenclature package
 \usepackage[font=small,skip=0pt]{caption}
 \makenomenclature
 \setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parskip}\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}
 \renewcommand{\cellset}{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.5}}
 \journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}

 \bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}

 \begin{document}
\section*{Appendix}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ c c } 
\toprule
\makecell{ parameters}  &  values \\   
%\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-6}%\midrule
\midrule
A &  1.5\\
F & 50     \\
S & 6   \\
B & 0  \\
D & 98   \\
R & 2 \\
I & 5  \\
Mutual  & 3 \\
Number  & 30 \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}\vspace{-\parskip}
\caption{The parameters with their value}

  Z=4, K=8, L=1, Y=18
\section*{References}

\bibliography{mybibfile}

BABCDEFGHIJKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789011121314151617181920
```

Comment: use `\begin{center}` before the table ans `\end{center}` after it

Comment: Is there a reason for not using the `table` environment?

Comment: @twimo You cannot use `\caption` outside of a float - this causes an error and your document does not compile in its current state. Please first fix those errors before worrying about formatting things like the end of `\centering`. Easiest solution would be to use a `table` environment, as suggested in egregs comment.

Comment: While you wait for an answer to this question, can you go back to your previous ones and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do?

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[font=small,skip=0pt]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\section*{Appendix}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ c c } \toprule
        \makecell{ parameters}  &  values \\   
        %\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-6}%\midrule
        \midrule
        A &  1.5\\
        F & 50     \\
        S & 6   \\
        B & 0  \\
        D & 98   \\
        R & 2 \\
        I & 5  \\
        Mutual  & 3 \\
        Number  & 30 \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \captionof{table}{The parameters with their value}
    Z=4, K=8, L=1, Y=18
\end{minipage}

\section*{References}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Answers should be self-contained.